# NestJs Version 9 How to reduce repetition my code

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, nestjs, typeorm

I hope you well.

I have an idea reduce the repetition in my service file

my code like this

`

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateBranchGroupDto } from './dto/create-branch-group.dto';
import { UpdateBranchGroupDto } from './dto/update-branch-group.dto';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { BranchGroup } from './entities/branch-group.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '@users/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class BranchGroupsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(BranchGroup)
    private branchGroupRepository: Repository<BranchGroup>,
  ) {}

  create(user: User, createBranchGroupDto: CreateBranchGroupDto) {
    createBranchGroupDto.createdBy = user.id;
    return this.branchGroupRepository.save(
      this.branchGroupRepository.create(createBranchGroupDto),
    );
  }

  async update(
    id: number,
    user: User,
    updateBranchGroupDto: UpdateBranchGroupDto,
  ) {
    updateBranchGroupDto.updatedBy = user.id;
    await this.branchGroupRepository.update(id, updateBranchGroupDto);
    const updatedBranchGroup = await this.branchGroupRepository.findOne({
      where: { id: id },
    });
    if (updatedBranchGroup) {
      return updatedBranchGroup;
    }

    throw new HttpException('Branch group not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }

  async remove(id: number, user: User) {
    await this.branchGroupRepository.update(id, { deletedBy: user.id});
    const deletedBranchGroup = await this.branchGroupRepository.softDelete(id);
    if (!deletedBranchGroup.affected) {
      throw new HttpException('Branch group not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}
```

in `create update remove`

I have to add user id in every function.
such as

create function add createdBy
update function add updatedBy
remove function add deletedBy

If I have more files, the more I have to repeat this every time for every file.

**

> Like a OOP inheritance

**

[image]